# How to handle Ajax.BeginForm() OnError OnFailure callback?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following ajax post in my view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateEmail", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnFailure = "showMessage(xhr.responseJSON.TypeMessage, xhr.responseJSON.Message)",
    OnSuccess = "showMessage(data.TypeMessage, data.Message); location.reload();",
    OnBegin = "$('#btnRefresh').attr('disabled', true)",
    OnComplete = "$('#btnRefresh').attr('disabled', false)",
 }))
```

And the controller:

```
public ActionResult UpdateEmail(EditEmailDTO model)
{      
        if (isValidCode)
        {
            //Code here to return a feedback json to be handle in OnSuccess callback - Working OK
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
        else 
        {
            //Here is the problem in production
            Response.StatusCode = 422; 
            feedback = new { Success = false, Message = MessageFeedback.InvalidCode, TypeMessage= TypeMessageFeedback.Error.ToString().ToLower() };
        }    
        catch (InvalidEmailException exception){ //Code Here    } 
        return Json(feedback, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

When im debuggin locally it works perfectly, the OnFailure is fired and i get the feedback on screen. But when i deploy it i just see on the Chrome Dev Tools Console that the server returned a 422 error and this message:
         `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'TypeMessage' of undefined`.

The script generated  in the `Ajax.BeginForm()` :

```
(function(xhr,status,error
 /**/) {
    showMessage(xhr.responseJSON.TypeMessage,        xhr.responseJSON.Message)
 })
```

Is there a difference in production and debuggin locally whith the **Response.StatusCode** errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I figure out the solution.

The problem is that IIS overrides the response in cases of errors (4xx and 5xx) response codes (even if is set manually on the Action method). Then the **xhr** object returned to the callback is the new object sent by the IIS and not my Json. The solution is to add this line on the Action:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Comment: We had a similar problem when we promoted our code from our local development environment to the Test server and this solved the problem.  Thanks!